# background-image is not working when using url() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, styled-components

im trying to put image in the background by using  `background-img:url(imageLing)`
but not working and it's return to me when inspect the element `background-image: url(assets/backgrounds/5.jpg);`
what is the issue :
this is my code

```
//login page 

<LoginWrapper img={`assets/backgrounds/${randomImage}.jpg`}>
        <Wrapper>
          <LoginForm onClickLogin={login} />
        </Wrapper>
      </LoginWrapper>
```

```
//css file using styled- components 

interface LoginProps {
  img: string;
}

export const LoginWrapper = styled.div<LoginProps>`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 93vh;
  background-image: url(${({ img }) => img});
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

React generally bundles your project before deployment which minifies images and changes image path. Hence, passing the path via props will not work. In order to get images to load properly, you have to reference them dynamically as an import.

**Login Page**

```
//login page 
import img from './assets/backgrounds/bg.gif'; // <= update this path according to your folder structure, i've added this path as an example

<LoginWrapper img={img}>
    <Wrapper>
      <LoginForm onClickLogin={login} />
    </Wrapper>
</LoginWrapper>
```

**CSS File Option 1 (using img from props)**

```
//css file using styled- components 

// interface LoginProps {
// img: string;
// }

export const LoginWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 93vh;
  background-image: url(${({ img }) => img});
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

**CSS File Option 2 (importing image in this file itself)**

```
//css file using styled- components 

import img from './assets/backgrounds/bg.gif'; // <= update this path according to your folder structure, i've added this path as an example

export const LoginWrapper = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 93vh;
  background-image: url(${img});
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
`;
```

Comment: is not working.

Comment: Is the image path correct ? Can you try importing the image directly in the CSS file once and check. For example: `background-image: url(${ img });`

Comment: how i can import the image it self ?

Comment: @AmmarALSananni I have edited my post and added `CSS File Option 2`. I have also edited `CSS File Option 1` and commented the interface which had type of img defined as string but it is an object here. You can try both these options now. Thanks

Comment: thank you for your answer , i think the issue is not with the props , it's with the url() doesn't ready the image for some reason .